# What was the story with Joker on death row?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

Ages ago I read a quite interesting story. Somebody committed murder by using Joker's laughing gas.

The Joker was accused for that crime and sentenced to death.

In the meantime Batman starts to believe in Jocker's innocence, and tries to find proof.

Can somebody help me to identify that story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the Laughing Gas but Joker Venom would be: [***The Joker - Devil's Advocate***](http://joker.wikia.com/wiki/The_Joker:_Devil%27s_Advocate)

[image]

> The United States Postal Service issues a commemorative series of stamps featuring some of the great comedians in American history. The Joker, greatly disgruntled by the fact that no stamp was printed in his name, vandalizes the post office. Subsequently, a succession of deaths occurs in Gotham City as a result of licking the back of the stamps, and the Joker's gruesome grin is drawn on the victims' faces.
>
> The Joker is caught by Batman and Robin while attempting to rob the post office's vault. The District Attorney seeks to hold the Joker responsible of all the crimes, and the Clown Prince of Crime is eventually **found guilty, being sentenced to death** for the first time after many inane attempts to get away with an insanity plea.
>
> The Joker is offended of being accused of a ludicrous crime, citing that a mastermind like him would operate on a much smarter level, and therefore considers himself innocent. However, **Batman is convinced as well that he is guiltless, and aims to prove it**.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much.